# CSS need inline element to appear next to { display: block; } element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to introduce a checkbox next to another element.   The problem is that the `a` element has been made a "block" by the CSS so that it appears at the correct height and width.  Being a block, I can't simply put another element next to it and hope it shows up there -- it shows up just below it.

A self-contained sample is shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
/* I don't have control over this */
a.btn {
        background-color: #B35905;
        color: #E6D389;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.normal{
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 125px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- I have some control over this -->
<a class="btn normal">Push Me</a><input type="checkbox">
<br>
<a class="btn normal">Push Me Too</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I'm looking for is the checkbox to appear immediately to the right of the  element, but without having to completely muck up the styling of the button.  Absolute positioning of the checkbox using the (known) size of the button seems wrong and dirty.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must keep the anchor a block element, set `float: left` to it. Don't forget to add

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

after the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="btn normal" style="float: left;">Push Me</a><input type="checkbox">
<br style="clear: both;">
<a class="btn normal">Push Me Too</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in two more css classes

```
.floatingButton{
    float:left;
}
.aCheckbox {
    xclear:left;
}
```

Then

```
<a class="btn normal floatingButton">Push Me</a><input class="aCheckbox" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <a class="btn normal">Push Me Too</a>
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this with the access that you do have?

```
<div style="width: 150px;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="float: right;"> 
  <a class="btn normal">Push Me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a `float: left` to the first `a` tag.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest possible way to get the checkbox beside the button while preserving the button's block styling would be to set the button's `display` property to `inline-block`. Surprisingly, using `display: inline-block` in this scenario will work in all modern browsers and IE 6 and above. `inline-block` is a little-known but highly useful property.